# How can I download older versions of STS?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I'm looking to download the `3.6.0 sts-bundle` but I cannot find the place to do this on https://spring.io/tools/sts/all.  I'm only seeing downloads for 3.6.1.  Does anyone know where this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: there is still an issue open to bring this download archive back to the spring.io site. In the meantime, let me know which version you should like to download and I will post the URLs (STS version, operating system, 32bit vs. 64bit).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for STS version 3.6.0 for Windows 7 and Mac OSX. (32 bit versions)

Comment: I'm looking for STS 3.6.1 32-bit Linux. Archive links on https://spring.io/tools/sts/all would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the download URL for OSX (32bit):
http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.0/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.RELEASE-e4.4-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz

(are you sure you wanna use 32bit on OSX? I would recommend to use the 64bit version so that you can run that on JDK7 or JDK8):
http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.0/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.RELEASE-e4.4-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

And here for Windows (32bit):
http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.0/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.RELEASE-e4.4-win32.zip

Comment: Hi, when you have a moment would you please post the download link for Windows(64bit)

Comment: The url can be inferred for Windows (64bit) as follows: <http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.0/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64.zip>

Comment: Is there a way now to find archived versions? I am looking for the 64 bit Windows version of 3.3.0.

Comment: http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.3.0/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.3.0.RELEASE-e4.3-win32-x86_64.zip

Comment: I need for mac 4.5.1 version? Can I get the link please ?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Previous-Versions

Answer (score 3):

I have the same need for version 3.5.1. win32-x86_64. I need to be in sync with my dev team's environment. Here's a link: http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.5.1/dist/e4.3/spring-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.3.2-win32-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 2):

Linux 64

Here the link for linux x64 ( is inferred from the links posted before)

http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.0/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.RELEASE-e4.4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

I use  Mint 17  KDE.   Luna 4.4.1 crashes when opening some windows (I am not sure if it is luna or kde) so I needed the previous version.

It may be useful to some one else.