# STS 3.6.1 on Windows using JDK 7 or 8: "No server selected" error

Tags: spring-tool-suite, tcserver

I run STS 3.6.1 on Windows 7 under either Java 7 or Java 8 JDK.

The "Pivotal tc Server Developer Editions v3.0" is created fine, using tc Server Developer Edition v3.0 and Tomcat 8. It runs fine. However, I cannot edit the runtime configuration. In the Edit Launch configuration dialog (that opens by clicking the "Open launch configuration" link) the error displays as "No server selected". Indeed, there is no Server available in the combo box.

No matter how I create the server (using existing or new tc Server setup) and no matter which JRE I use, the launch configuration will not "stick". The Edit Configuration dialog lets me change the VM Arguments (under Arguments tab) but the changes are not saved.

This error seemed to be introduced in 3.6.1 and tc Server v3.0. It worked in 3.6.0 that used tcServer v2.9

Any ideas of a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of not showing Pivotal tc Server 3.0 on the launch config Server tab in the launch config wizard is in fact turned out to be a tc server eclipse integration problem.
It's fixed now. Please install update tc server integration from this update site:
http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/eclipse-integration-tcserver/nightly

P.S. Please report any other problems you notice with tc 3.0 server eclipse integration :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with TC Server rather than STS. I've got the same issue with STS 3.6.1 and TC Server 3.0.0, but creating a server in STS 3.6.1 using my older TC Server 2.9.3 works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you, I agree. Unfortunately the tc server 3.0 starts up fine, it just cannot be edited (and I cannot trust the configuration). For now I switched to STS bundle that uses tc Server 2.9.6. Too bad they do not make it easy to download an older version of STS bundle - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567877/how-can-i-download-older-versions-of-sts. The 3.6.0 will update itself to 3.6.1 but still use tc server 2.9.6 (and Tomcat 7). I hope they fix it soon.